# Not able to access context dictionary values using variable key using filter in Django template

Tags: django

Although I have used a custom filter to access the dictionary's values with variable key, I am not able to do so. Below are the code snippet.

view.py

```
def DBConnect(request):
    c = {}
    c['dbs'] = get_all_db() #returns an array of db.
    for db in c['dbs']:
         c[db] = get_all_tables(db) #returns all the tables in db and storing in context dictionary with db name as key.

    return render_to_response('test.html', c)
```

As an example c will contain followings:
 c = {'dbs':[u'db1', u'db2'], u'db1' : [u'tb1', u'tb2'], u'db2' : [u'tb21', u'tb22']}

app_filter.py

```
@filter.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

Test.html
....
....

```
{%for db in dbs%}
     do something with {{db}} <- this is fine, I am getting all the dbs here.
     {{ c | get_item : db }} <- This code is not working, If I directly pass dbname literal than it is working fine.
{% endfor %}
```

Please suggest if I should pass the context in different way to overcome this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you pass 'dbs' into test template? As per the code above, you are passing in 'c' which is dictionary that has 'dbs' as one of its key.

Comment: Thank you Rohan and AKS for your replies. I am fairly new to the Django framework. I will be implementing these solution and will mark as answer. I am very sure that both solutions will do the work.Thank you AKS for explanation this really helps me understanding few of the things related to Django. Thanks both of you again. +1 for both of you.. :-)

Comment: @Amit: Thank you for the comments and we are glad to help. Please also read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `c` is a context, it is not directly available in the template. What is available are the keys/values you set in the context i.e. If your context is like following:

```
 c = {'dbs':[u'db1', u'db2'], u'db1' : [u'tb1', u'tb2'], u'db2' : [u'tb21', u'tb22']}
```

You will be able to access `dbs`, `db1` and `db2` as variables inside the template. Here keys are translated to variables and the values in the context are the values of those variables e.g. when you access `dbs` you are directly accessing `c['dbs']`.

Considering what you are doing, I would choose to do it like following:

```
def DBConnect(request):
    c = {}
    dbs = get_all_db() #returns an array of db.
    c['dbtbls'] = {db: get_all_tables(db) for db in dbs}
    return render_to_response('test.html', c)
```

Now, in the template you can directly access `dbtbls.items`:

```
{% for db, tbls in dbtbls.items %}
     do something with {{ db }} here.
     {{ tbls }} # this is the list of all the tables in the db
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In django template context variables are accessed directly as you see from `dbs`. You don't need to use dictionary like access.

You can slightly change the context to suit your code as

```
def DBConnect(request):
    c = {}
    c['dbs'] = get_all_db() #returns an array of db.
    c['dbtables'] = {}
    for db in c['dbs']:
         c['dbtables'][db] = get_all_tables(db)

    return render_to_response('test.html', c)
```

Then in template you can use

```
{%for db in dbs%}
     do something with {{db}} here.
     {{ dbtables | get_item : db }} 
{% endfor %}
```